# How can I set up m:n relationships in lithium?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, relationship, lithium

I have 3 tables in my MySQL database:

- books (id, title)
- keywords (id, keyword)
- books_keywords (book_id, keyword_id)

What is the best way to set up models and controllers in li3 to retrieve book titles with their keywords?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

li3 only provides one-to-one, one-to-many, and many-to-one relationships. Li3 core developers suggest to avoid many-to-many relationships as they can lead to unexpected problems and are a sign of architectural design of your app.

Have a look at: http://li3.me/docs/book/manual/1.x/models/relationships